# "Unspecified error" from javascript in my Silverlight application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application written in C# that utilizes the Bing Maps SDK.  In this application I have a page with some javascript functions to expose functions within the application.  The application registers the Bing MapControl in the MainPage's constructor with:

```
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", new MapControl(this.BingMap));
```

In the javascript function, I call the methods of the application like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClearMap() {
        var control = document.getElementById('silverlightControl');
        control.Content.Page.ClearMap();
    }
</script>
```

However, whenever I refer to the control.Content.Page property in a javascript function, I get an "Unspecified error".  Even just setting it to a variable will cause the error, for example:

```
var page = control.Content.Page;
```

Here is the strange part.  I am using this silverlight application from 2 other applications.  One is a windows service, and the other a winform application.  The winform embeds a visible WebBrowser into its form and uses that to call the javascript functions.  When using the winform, everything works fine with no errors.

The error only occurs when calling these functions from the windows service.  The service instantiates a WebBrowser object just like the winform application does, and initializes everything in the same way.  The only difference is that it's running as a service, and the WebBrowser is not visible nor embedded in any forms.  Could that fact possibly cause this error?

I currently have the winform application, the windows service, and the silverlight application's webservice all running on my own local machine.

**UPDATE**

After Gnostus' comments, I figured out that the main issue I'm having is that the "Page" object is not being created because the App class never gets initialized after navigating to the webservice from the windows service-based WebBrowser.  The winform app and the service both do this the exact same way:

```
WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:56062/BingMapsWebServiceTestPage.aspx");
while (WebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

I added some code to the MainPage's constructor where it calls HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", new MapControl(this.BingMap)); that will log some text when it gets hit.  When I run the above code in the WebBrowser of the winform application, the following occurs:

1. The DocumentCompleted event gets fired twice (once by the browser and I assume once by the silverlight control)
2. The App() is intialized and the "Page" element successfully added in the MainPage's constructor
3. The above while loop completes

When I do the same from the windows service, it does #1 and #3, but not #2.  Step 2 only gets hit when I call a javascript function that refers to the Page object, and only after it errors.

**UPDATE 2**

After messing around in a new winform application, I discovered that the silverlight control will fail to load upon calling Navigate() whenever the WebBrowser or its parent form is invisible.  I found that it's possible to still call my javascript functions if the parent form is hidden AFTER the silverlight application has finished loading.  Does anyone know a better way to force the silverlight app to load aside from flashing up a visible form?  Is it even possible to show a form from a windows service, or am I going to have to rethink this whole thing as a console application?

Comment: No chance the element does not actually get grabbed out of the dom?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Sorry, javascript isn't my strong suit and I'm completely new to silverlight.  Do you mean that something might be removing the "Page" element?  I can't imagine what could be, and I would think if something were it would also affect the winform application.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the silverlightControl element is being found too.  If I set a variable with "var control = document.getElementById('silverlightControl');", then refer to "control.Content", it works without any errors.

Comment: ah that was more or less my question, so my only help is to get firebug, and break point after you set the control variable and look through its properties and make sure the Page property exists.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  After some more debugging, I discovered that it actually hadn't been created yet.  The MainPage's constructor was being called AFTER the javascript function when running in the windows service, so the Page element didn't exist at the time.  This is not the case in the winform, but I don't know why.  Now I just need to figure out why the MainPage isn't instantiated when I call the javascript function.

Comment: May want to hook into the onload event

Comment: After looking at it some more, I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  I can't see any difference between how I load the WebBrowser and navigate to the silverlight app on the localhost between the windows service and the winform application.

Comment: One thing I don't get is why it's calling the App() constructor AFTER the Unspecified Error was already thrown by the javascript function.  It's like trying to refer to the Page element causes it to initialize.  I tried calling other javascript functions that don't refer to this element, and they work fine but don't initialize the App or MainPage.

Comment: Check out how http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/12/04/silverlight-tip-how-to-inject-and-execute-javascript-function-s-on-the-fly-from-silverlight.aspx is doing it, Im curious if maybe that would be waiting till the App() executes to inject the javascrpit and then everything will be initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I seem to be doing everything pretty much the same as him.  I'm fairly sure at this point that the issue doesn't lie with the silverlight app, but with the windows service and the WebBrowser client.  For both the service and the winforms app, I set up and navigate to the silverlight app like so:

Comment: WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:56062/BingMapsWebServiceTestPage.aspx");
DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
while (WebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

In the winform app, the following occurs:

1.  The DocumentCompleted event gets fired twice (once by the browser and i assume once by the silverlight control)
2.  The App() is intialized and the "Page" element successfully added 
3.  The above while loop compeltes

Comment: But when I do the same from the service, #2 never happens, the 2 DocumentCompleted events both fire then the while loop exits.  I don't understand what's happening differently that allows the web app to initialize from the winform application.